# How can I retrieve crucial git information after a power outage corrupted git files?

Tags: git, github, version-control

and thank you in advance for any help!
I recently made a git commit, and in the middle of the commit, my computer lost power. Upon running `git status`, I get:

`error: object file .git/objects/53/e4ea5d9c33089c5bc20b64b5a24f6b9f9fa62f is empty
error: object file .git/objects/53/e4ea5d9c33089c5bc20b64b5a24f6b9f9fa62f is empty
fatal: loose object 53e4ea5d9c33089c5bc20b64b5a24f6b9f9fa62f (stored in .git/objects/53/e4ea5d9c33089c5bc20b64b5a24f6b9f9fa62f) is corrupt`

This is a big problem, and there are a ton of missing/corrupted git files shown by running `git fsck --full`. Thankfully it appears that all of my actual files are fine. I did some reading on the subject and I think the simplest solution is to clone the remote repository, then take the .git folder of the remote and move it into my local folder. I tried cloning the remote, but no .git folder was present.

**How can I get the .git folder from the remote repository so that I can continue committing using my current local files? I don't care if my local commit history since the last push is deleted, I just need to continue working on my current local files.**

Thank you very much! Help is needed because this is a very important repo.

Comment: Is this on your local filesystem or is it a server? Did you push your commits to a remote server of any kind, such as GitHub or BitBucket?

Comment: "I tried cloning the remote, but no .git folder was present." If you correctly cloned the remote, then there **must** be a `.git` folder. This is guaranteed by the way that Git works. How are you looking for the `.git` folder? If you use `ls` on Linux or Mac, this folder will not show because it is considered "hidden". You need to do `ls -a` instead. If you are on Windows, be sure that you can see all hidden files.

Comment: The corruption took place on my local filesystem. I have not pushed the corrupted commit to GitHub but I have consistently been pushing to github up until now. I only had a few unpushed commits when the power loss took place.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice , that's exactly what I thought but no .git folder is present in the clone I downloaded. I made sure to show all hidden folders (linux) and it is not there. Could it be because I cloned a specific branch, and not master branch (which is not the most updated)? Do I need to clone master? Interestingly, the .gitignore file is there, but not the .git folder. Thank you for your help by the way!

Comment: "the clone I downloaded" What do you mean by this? How did you "download" a clone? Did you run `git clone`? Also how are you looking for the `.git` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest running `git clone <remote URL>`. This will create a new directory with the same state as the remote. Then you can copy the local files from your original directory to this new one and continue working from there.

Comment: Thank you! The problem from earlier is that I was not properly cloning the repository, just downloading its contents in a .zip file. I was able to get back on track. Have a great day!

Comment: @RichardHausman Yes, GitHub only provides the most recent source code in the ZIP file. It does not contain the full Git repository that includes change history.